# Kali beeja mantra

Tags: mantras, kali

I am confused about the pronunciation of kali beeja mantra. while some articles say the pronunciation is "kreem" but the spelling clearly shows the it should be "kring", also some tantrik say that it is neither. Can someone site reference to the correct kali beeja mantra with pronunciation?

Comment: Could you add the devanagari version too for reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct Kali mantra is Krim.

> The Bijas thus have a meaning. They indicate the Artha or Devata which
>   they are. What that Devata is, is taught to the Sadhaka, just as the
>   child learns that rose means a particular flower, and that rice and
>   milk are the names for particular forms of food and drink which he
>   takes.
>
> The Bijas of the five Bhutas, that is, of the Devatas of the four
>   forms of sensible matter, are Ha, Ya, Ra, La, Va, with Chandra-bindu.
>   Where there is more than one letter, each has its meaning. As examples
>   I here select twelve Bija-mantras (in their popular sense), the
>   meanings of which are given in the 6th chapter of the Varada-Tantra as
>   quoted in the well-known Bengali compendium known as the Pranatoshini.
>   I may here observe that the meaning of individual letters is given in
>   the Bijakosas, such as the Tantrabidhana. The Varada-Tantra, Ch 6
>   says:
>
> .....
>
> Krim
>
> *Ka* Kali brahma *ra* proktam Mahamayarthakasca *i*,
>
> Visvamatarthako *nado* *bindur*dukhahararthakah
>
> That is, *Ka* is Kali. *Ra* is said to be Brahma. *I* means Mahamaya.
>   *Nada* means Mother of the universe. *Bindu* means Dispeller of sorrow. With that Devi 
>   Kalika should be worshipped for cessation of
>   sorrow.

**The Garland of Letters** by Sir John Woodroffe

The book does not talk of pronunciation but I have heard Krim pronounced as it is spelled.

Comment: I failed to understand the explanation at the last para; while the word end with "m" the para uses the word "Nada" which starts with "n" and not "m"

Comment: I checked with the book and I have not mistyped. I am guessing that Nada which means mother of the universe or Mata is inserted as m in the bija and hence Krim ends with M. The bija mantra Hrim for Maya also has the same ending.

Comment: Is the reference from "varada tantra" or garland of letters? If possible can you give link to the pdf?

Comment: The reference is from the garland of letters.

Comment: I unintentionally downvoted this, swiped across my screen without realizing, & now can’t take off the downvote  Anyway I think is a good answer & the downvote was by mistake. Won’t let me remove it ! Then I got critic badge or something  Weird

Comment: Don't worry. Accidents happen. Thanks for letting me know.